# Bootstrap DateTime Picker set default date to yesterday

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, date, default, datetimepicker

Does anyone know how to set the bootstrap datetimepicker to default date be yesterday?  That is the highlighted day when the calendar pops up.  I am using the one that has documented options here but having a tough time figuring out how to do it: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/  I was trying something like this but not sure if I am on the right track. Thanks!

```
    $(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker(({ language: "en", pickTime: true}));

    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = date.getFullYear();

    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        defaultDate: day+"/"+month+"/"+year //<--change the order if other format is set, this is DD/MM/YYYY Format
    });
```

Comment: I just edited to show that above I am also referencing the datepicker to specify the english language so it does not show Chinese characters.  For some reason I still am not getting the default date to show up as yesterday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using [moment subtract](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/) to manipulate the date as desired.

```
$(function () {
    $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
        format: "MM/DD/YYYY - HH:mm",
        defaultDate: moment().subtract(1, 'days'),
        useCurrent: false
    });
});
```

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/spasticdonkey/bkqx96bk/1/

Comment: This one worked for me thank you so much and thanks to everyone who helped on this ticket.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var yest = new Date(new Date().getTime() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    var month = yest.getMonth();
    var year = yest.getFullYear();
    var date = yest.getDate();
    var startDate = new Date(year, month, date);
    $('#date').datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    });
    $('#date').datepicker('setDate', startDate);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").date(moment().subtract(1, 'days'),);
```